# getAssets() showing error in eclipse

Tags: android, file

I'm trying to be able to search for a string in a file in the assets folder. the getassets().open is saying its undefined. 
I read somewhere this way works.
Here is my code:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class Search {

 public static void LoadStuff(String Name) {

      Scanner reader = null;
      try {
          reader = new Scanner(new File(getAssets().open("myFile.txt"))); 
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.d("damn", "FAIL");
      }
         if(reader != null)
            Load(reader);
   }




private static void Load(Scanner reader) {
      while (reader.hasNext()) {
         String result = reader.next();
         if (result.equals("water")) {   
            while (result != "KEYEND") {
               int index = reader.nextInt();
               Log.d("Index", String.valueOf(index));
            }
         }
      }
            reader.close();
   }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling getAssets, but you don't actually have a context to load from. You need to pass your application context into this class.

```
public static void LoadStuff(Context appContext, String fileName){
```

Then

```
appContext.getAssets().open(fileName);
```

The `Scanner` constructor also accepts in `InputStream`, so your line will become:

```
 reader = new Scanner(getAssets().open("myFile.txt"));
```

Comment: You dont need the `File`, the `Scanner` constructor accepts an `InputStream`.

Comment: Just updated my post. Glad I could help, good luck and Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 3):

First use `Context` as Matt Clark Answered..

Then Second thing is that `getAssets().open("myFile.txt")` is `InputStream` not `File`

So read it like

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("myFile.txt");
reader = new Scanner(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

In-order to use getAssets() method you need to have BaseApplicationContext or Activity Context.

Try to use context.getAssets()

```
 AssetManager assets = activityContext.getResources().getAssets();
 InputStream inputStream = assets.open("SlideImages/"+fullImage);
```

Comment: Because assests.open is an inputstream so try to read as inputstream and convert (wirte) to file